# Does running different processes in fork mode ensures that the every process is using different core?

Tags: node.js, pm2, node-cluster

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@eyalronel1984/auto-scaling-real-time-nodejs-applications-on-aws-the-last-tutorial-youll-need-eba1d2c88a4c) tutorial, and have a question :

- Will creating different fork processes ensure that every process is
  being created using different core from vCPU? Or is there we can
  check that somehow?

Experts thoughts on it are highly welcomed!

Comment: I don't think it is guaranteed that it will use different vCPU. It always depends on OS Process scheduler. This is to utilise the all available core. On production server probability will be higher because i am assuming it will be dedicated for application and no other process running with huge computation. If you are thinking of dedicating vCPU you can use process CPU affinity, This is ideally not good idea better lets OS does it work.

Comment: In that way, the link I am following for socket io with clustering and HAproxy won't be worth, as it leave behind major vCPU utilization part :(

Comment: It is still useful. So Node.js is single threaded that means it utilise one core per process. Now if you have multi core machine like 8 core and lets assume that one core is used by OS ( Although that will not be case), One by your node.js process then other 6 core are ideal. So to utilise those six you will be creating a node process cluster. which results is multiple process so os can schedule task with available cores. With this scheduling there is no guarantee that all core will be used because it all depends on the computation inside process and although all process running on machine

Comment: If you are from java/.net background, in java and .net thread can utilise different core and parallel computation.